# Getting Class Not Found: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport when using GroovyClassLoader in Java

Tags: java, groovy

I have a groovy script like so:

```
@Grab('com.univocity:univocity-parsers:2.0.0')
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.*;

class MyCsvParser {

}
```

And I want to load this class in my java application via `GroovyClassLoader`. But the `@Grab` somehow yields in an ivy exception:

```
SomeJavaClass {
    void someMethod() {
         String script = FileUtils.readFileToString("the groovy File");
         Class c = new GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader())).parse(script);
    }
}
```

Stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 more
```

When I comment out the `@Grab` everything works just fine. How can I enable the Grapes in `GroovyClassLoader`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should add the ivy dependency. It's not added by default because it's declared as non-transitive. Ivy is the library which manages the dependencies loaded by `@Grab`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
  <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Add this dependency to what?

Comment: No seriously, what is this xml file and where is it located?

Comment: In your pom.xml if you are using maven.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `gradle.build`

```
configurations {
  ivy
}

dependencies {
  ivy "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.4.0"
 ...
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
  groovyClasspath += configurations.ivy
}
```