# Jenkins Pipeline Shared Library using @Grab breaks Spock tests

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, spock

I am trying to add a 3rd party library to one of my Pipeline Shared Library code, following the "Extending with Shared Library" instructions here:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries

```
@GrabResolver(name='custom', root='http://my.nexus/maven')
@Grab("com.packageA.serviceA:artifactA:1.0.0")

import com.packageA.serviceA.ClassA
```

This failed with IvySettings class not found. Following another StackOverflow post:

[Getting Class Not Found: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport when using GroovyClassLoader in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829990/getting-class-not-found-org-apache-ivy-core-report-resolvereport-when-using-gro)

I had to add this to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
        <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I got past the IvySettings not found problem. But all my Spock unit tests for the class that I am adding @Grab for, failed with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mypackage.pipeline.client.MyClient
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:386)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:91)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.GroovyMockFactory.create(GroovyMockFactory.java:66)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:45)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:281)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.GroovyMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:199)
    at myRollbackTest.Missing object(myRollbackTest.groovy:184)
```

These tests are using GroovyMock and GroovySpy.

Has anyone ever made Grab to work with GroovyMock/Spy from Spock?

Comment: Without a reproducible test case ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I am afraid nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Good point. But I think I have a theory. Will post the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add the @Grab on a non-PSL code in src/com/packageA/serviceA, i.e: not under var/* .

According to the Jenkins documentation, @Grab only works on Pipeline Shared library code.

I worked around this by using the @Grab a Pipeline shared library function, and calling this function from my non-PSL code in src/com/packageA/serviceA.